# Is there any algorithm or procedure for an *automatic* translation of English sentences to symbolic logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I see that there are methods for processing a sentence manually, I mean looking for "if", "then", "and", "or", etc. and then generating the equivalent logical expression. However, I was looking for something where I can give many sentences and the algorithm would generate the equivalent logical expressions automatically.

Thanks and regards.

Masud

Comment: You'd need to look into natural language processing.  See e.g., [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68398/semantic-natural-language-processing-from-texts-to-logical-expressions-univer) question.  But this is really more a question of human language than it is a math question.

Answer (score 2):

No, because you will have to deal with the [ambiguity of "or"](https://translation-blog.trustedtranslations.com/the-ambiguity-of-or-2012-05-23.html) in English, which can have an *inclusive* or an *exclusive* meaning.

Comment: I think $\dots$ even human can't deal with it in this case

Comment: Example (with categories changed) of a statement on a certain graduate entrance exam (not U.S.) I'm reviewing items from, this being in a section testing syllogisms/Venn-diagram type reasoning: *comedies and blockbusters are popular*. OK, so how is this supposed to be interpreted, union of comedies and blockbusters is a subset of popular (natural language reading) OR intersection of comedies and blockbusters is a subset of popular (what should be correct for context of the item)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is presently no general procedure or algorithm that is $100$% accurate $100$% of the time. Such an algorithm is a pursuit of natural language processing. However, there do exist heuristics for translating statements from natural language to symbolic form. For example, "and" or "but" typically refer to conjunction whereas "or" is inclusive disjunction and "either... or" is exclusive disjunciton. Terms like "all" or "none" typically denote universal quantification whereas terms like "some" refer to existential quantification. Moreover, if ever the translation is tricky, I typically rewrite the statement over and over, each time making them more formal and being careful to preserve the meaning, until finally they are in a form that I can easily translate symbolically. The process of translation is largely complicated by the ambiguity and inconsistencies that exist in human language, but progress has been made and is being made toward a "general algorithm," - whether we will ever actually arrive at one remains to be known. Some of the best models are not hard coded rules; they are essentially "black boxes" that are the products of neural networks.